# Android listview is returning null?

Tags: android, xml, listview, nullpointerexception, android-fragments

So I'm trying to make a tabbed application...But it keeps crashing with null pointer exception . I checked through all the variables that could be causing a null pointer and I think I've narrowed it down.

```
ListView activeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activelist);
if(activeList == null) {
  Log.e("com.name.app", "activeList null");
}
```

This returns a null. Should it? I'm using fragments to try and build a tabbed layout. This is the xml it's referencing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/activelist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:persistent="true" >    
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you for any help!

Edit:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabs_layout);
```

That's what my contentview looks like.

Edit:
This is what my final code looked like!

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    LinearLayout mContainer = (LinearLayout)     inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag1_layout, null); 
    ListView activeList = (ListView) mContainer.findViewById(R.id.activelist);
```

Comment: RU inflating the view or doing as setContentview()???

Comment: Look if that listview is declared in the same layout which you are setting as a content of that activity.

Comment: It is not, but now I'm trying to figure out how to inflate that. Is there any easy way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
LinearLayout mContainer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linear_layout, null); 
ListView activeList = (ListView) mContainer.findViewById(R.id.activelist);
```

Where R.layout.linear_layout is the id of `LinearLayout` which contains your `ListView`.

Comment: By RelativeLayout do you mean LinearLayout? Would I have to add an ID to the LinearLayout I have posted above? What would the inflater variable look like?

Comment: I modified with linearlayour but fro this issue it will be the same. I'm not sure where exactly you want to "inflate" your list.

Comment: R.layout.linear_layout
<-- Where's that supposed to be in my xml?

Comment: post your R.layout.tabs_layout please

Comment: Oh wait! I got it! I'll post my final code above. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Did you reffer in your activity to your XML layout?

You can do this in your oncreate method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView.(R.layout.your_XML_file_name);
}
```

Comment: Oh! No I have another ContentView selected, but that's necessary. But I believe I need to inflate the textview that I need to use?

Comment: does this work?     ListView tv = (ListView ) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.yourLV, null);